# HTML element not stretching to fit full screen when site is mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have deployed the site [here](https://v2.extrado.gg). Everything works but if you scale down the page to a mobile-size, you will notice that there is a huge space at the right side of the screen. Not sure what it is? Normally, I don't have to write posts on here because somebody has asked the same question but this time I couldn't find anything.

Hoping someone can help. The HTML doesn't extend to the full page even though its styling says for it to go to 100%. Let me know if you need any other details, really hoping someone can help.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem here on my system (tested with Chrome, Firefox, Edge). But there is a horizontal scrollbar when viewport width > 840px. You might want to start with figuring out where this comes from ...

Comment: The problem you mentioned here is not reproducible. Its showing perfectly fine in my Chrome Android. Nothing seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS and remove `width: 100vw !important;` from `html` tag

```
img{
   max-width: 100%
}
```

Check screenshot https://prnt.sc/1nya57a

Comment: Why does this work? I added that in as an attempt to fix it and forgot to remove it. Why does image tag max width 100% fix this issue?

Comment: Because you have not mentioned any width on the image when you scale the screen image doesn't scale